# confidence interval function only gives lower CI

Tags: r, function

I wrote a simple function to calculate confidence interval

```
data<-seq(1,25)

ci<-function(x){
     df<-length(x)-1
     t<-qt(0.975,df=df)
     m<-mean(x)
     sd<-sd(x)
     n<-length(x)
     se<-sd/sqrt(n)
     (m+t*se)
     (m-t*se)
}

ci(data)

#9.962024
```

As you can see it is giving me only one value `(m-t*se)` and not two whereas in the function I have calculated `(m+t*se)` as well. What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Yes I know to use `quantile`. I am just trying to teach myself to write functions.

Comment: Your function has no explicit return statement. Therefore, only the final evaluated element gets returned.

Comment: So how do I add a return statement? Sorry I am not really versed with functions

Comment: There are already two answers telling you how to do that. However, I would advise you to spend some time reading on creating functions in R. They are awesome and can make your life a lot easier, but it helps to know about things like returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R` functions will return a single object. Either you specifically define that object, by using the `return` function, or it will automatically return the last evaluated call. If you want to return multiple values, you'll have to combine them into a single object first.

For your example, this could be done like this:

```
ci<-function(x){
     df<-length(x)-1
     t<-qt(0.975,df=df)
     m<-mean(x)
     sd<-sd(x)
     n<-length(x)
     se<-sd/sqrt(n)
     c(upper = m+t*se, lower = m-t*se)
}
```

Or you could return explicitly:

```
ci<-function(x){
     df<-length(x)-1
     t<-qt(0.975,df=df)
     m<-mean(x)
     sd<-sd(x)
     n<-length(x)
     se<-sd/sqrt(n)
     return(c(upper = m+t*se, lower = m-t*se))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Heroka mentioned, a function without an explicit return statement will only return the final evaluated element. Therefore you can simply add the return statement as such:

```
ci<-function(x){
    df<-length(x)-1
    t<-qt(0.975,df=df)
    m<-mean(x)
    sd<-sd(x)
    n<-length(x)
    se<-sd/sqrt(n)
    return(c((m+t*se),(m-t*se)))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this and it works. If someone knows something more elegant or concise, please let me know.

```
ci<-function(x){
 df<-length(x)-1
 t<-qt(0.975,df=df)
 m<-mean(x)
 sd<-sd(x)
 n<-length(x)
 se<-sd/sqrt(n)
 up<-m+t*se
 lw<-m-t*se   
 my_list<-c(up,lw)
 return(my_list)
}

ci(data)
```